# vue3 + vue-i18n + vitest TypeError: _ctx.$t is not a function when run tests

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, vitest, vue-i18n

I use vitest to test my Vue3 application. Project uses vue-i18n library.

I wrote a simple test to check vitest functionality. My vue file uses `$t` to use translations, i18n stores.
`AboutPage.spec.js:`

```
import { describe, it, expect } from 'vitest'
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/vue'
import AboutPage from './AboutPage.vue'

describe('AboutPage', () => {
  it('should render correctly', () => {
    render(AboutPage)
    expect()
  })
})
```

But when I run vitest, it gives me the error:

```
FAIL  src/pages/AboutPage.spec.js > AboutPage > should render correctly
TypeError: _ctx.$t is not a function
 ❯ src/pages/AboutPage.vue:6:34
      4|   <main-container>
      5|     <div class="container-fluid">
      6|       <h1 class="text-center">{{ $t('pages.about_page.heading') }}</h1>
       |                                  ^
      7|       <div class="px-5 py-3">
      8|         <p>
 ❯ renderFnWithContext node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:762:13
 ❯ Module.renderSlot node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:2818:53
 ❯ Proxy._sfc_render src/components/MainContainer.vue:10:27
 ❯ renderComponentRoot node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:812:16
 ❯ ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:5657:46 
 ❯ ReactiveEffect.run node_modules/@vue/reactivity/dist/reactivity.cjs.js:182:19
 ❯ instance.update node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:5770:51
 ❯ setupRenderEffect node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:5778:5
 ❯ mountComponent node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:5568:5
```

`AboutPage.vue`:

```
<template>
  <navbar-item />

  <main-container>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <h1 class="text-center">{{ $t('pages.about_page.heading') }}</h1>
      <div class="px-5 py-3">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Rem ipsa a corrupti sint aperiam
          minima in inventore architecto culpa quae minus perferendis, hic ipsum vel quidem ab
          placeat esse quam?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. In tempore
          maiores, ducimus harum, illo sed provident, obcaecati ab facilis esse cum sint voluptas
          soluta temporibus delectus aliquid necessitatibus consequuntur incidunt. Lorem ipsum dolor
          sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia, totam ab? Veniam asperiores maiores porro
          dolores omnis temporibus, repudiandae tenetur officiis assumenda reprehenderit blanditiis,
          beatae animi quasi a consequatur ea?
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita, minima odio eveniet
          assumenda architecto fuga iste doloribus temporibus nam? Eius, dolorum inventore! Totam
          quibusdam reprehenderit ad corrupti aut earum quia. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
          adipisicing elit. Sint recusandae molestias ullam, ipsam sapiente suscipit nostrum! Error
          molestiae quis mollitia ipsam unde nam facilis, et voluptates odit ad dignissimos optio.
          Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis ullam nesciunt minima hic.
          Debitis explicabo neque architecto soluta. Adipisci rerum, nemo excepturi harum est
          dolorum odit voluptates veritatis similique laudantium.
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita, minima odio eveniet
          assumenda architecto fuga iste doloribus temporibus nam? Eius, dolorum inventore! Totam
          quibusdam reprehenderit ad corrupti aut earum quia. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
          adipisicing elit. Sint recusandae molestias ullam, ipsam sapiente suscipit nostrum! Error
          molestiae quis mollitia ipsam unde nam facilis, et voluptates odit ad dignissimos optio.
          Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis ullam nesciunt minima hic.
          Debitis explicabo neque architecto soluta. Adipisci rerum, nemo excepturi harum est
          dolorum odit voluptates veritatis similique laudantium.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <new-notification-toast />
  </main-container>
</template>

<script setup>
import NavbarItem from '../components/NavbarItem.vue'
import MainContainer from '../components/MainContainer.vue'
import NewNotificationToast from '../components/NewNotificationToast.vue'
</script>
```

`vitest.config.js`:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config'
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";

export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    environment: "jsdom",
    globals: true,
  },
  plugins: [vue(),],
})
```

How to solve this problem?

I expect it run without this error.

Comment: You need to use vue plugins that your comps use or mock them. The way you do this is specific to test lib (testing-library), not test runner (vitest)